# SQL query question from an absolute beginner

Tags: sql

All, I am new to SQL and am trying to put a query together. I have two `tables`, `users`, and `orders`. I want to return certain fields from `orders`, and append the results with a field from `users`. The common field in both tables is `employeeID`. My query returns a syntax error. I have tried it several different ways, with inner join, and with just plain join, right, left, full (shooting in the dark here. As I said, I am very new to this).

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT orders.clientid, orders.ordertrackingid, orders.clientrefno, orders.dconame, orders.dstreet, orders.dcity, orders.dzip, orders.dzone, orders.employeeid, users.username
where orders.status = 'n'
inner join orders on users.employeeid = orders.employeeid;
```

The error I get from is at here:

SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.
  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'inner'.

Any suggestions or help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error message is same as your script.

Comment: Yeah, I was too quick on the CTRL+C trigger.

Answer (score 0):

In general the Query structure is :

```
SELECT -> FROM - > [WHERE] -> [GROUP BY] -> [HAVING] -> [ORDER BY] -> . . .
```

`[]` denotes option clauses.

So, i would rewrite your query as :

```
select o.clientid, o.ordertrackingid, o.clientrefno, o.dconame, o.dstreet, o.dcity, o.dzip, o.dzone, o.employeeid, u.username 
from users u inner join 
     orders o
     on u.employeeid = o.employeeid
where o.status = 'n';
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see the error message but you seems you missed to add "FROM users". Also where should be after INNER JOIN. You can see corrected script here :

```
SELECT orders.clientid
    , orders.ordertrackingid
    , orders.clientrefno
    , orders.dconame
    , orders.dstreet
    , orders.dcity
    , orders.dzip
    , orders.dzone
    , orders.employeeid
    , users.username 
FROM users
inner join orders on users.employeeid = orders.employeeid
where orders.status = 'n' ;
```

Comment: I edited the original to show the error message.  But...your suggestion worked. Thank you so much. So, one more question: why do I only need the FROM for Users when I am pulling stuff from both tables?

Comment: You need one from as its for both as a join like from (Users and Orders)

Answer (score 0):

Just that you missed one table to join that was users with from clause

```
SELECT orders.clientid, 
orders.ordertrackingid, 
orders.clientrefno, orders.dconame, 
orders.dstreet, orders.dcity, 
orders.dzip, orders.dzone, 
orders.employeeid, users.username 
from users
inner join orders on 
users.employeeid = orders.employeeid
where orders.status = 'n'  ;
```

Comment: What is happening here is you joined users and orders on condition as employeeid so first it will join both tables on some related column then you are wanting as a filter after a join that will come via where clause saying where `orders.status='n'`